# How can I change the activity after the user signed in or signed up in my android application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am going to manage the activity. In my current activity diagram, I have an activity for the user when they use my application and they will see an activity about signup or signin. After the user signin or signup, how can I handle the user when they closed the app, and visit our app how can I skip the signin or signup activity? And stored the username and go to the home activity and show the another function?

Comment: What you are looking for is `SharedPreferences`. You can store key value pairs. So after login, store the token in `SharedPreferences` and then next visit, check the preferences if token is already present.

Comment: Save an access token or login token after successful sign in/up in `SharedPreferences` and in the `SplashActivity` or Launcher Activity, retrieve the stored token, check it and based on it, start an intent.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldnt start app with login activity.

if you start app with home activity and at home activity's onCreate function you can check if user sign in before and if not you can open login activity.

here is example:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_messages)
    
    verifyUserLogin()
}

fun verifyUserLogin(){
    if (user_login == true) return

    val intent = Intent(this, loginActivity::class.java)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to your question, first to handle if the user is already logged in or not you can use `SharedPreferences` to check and accordingly create an `intent` to either login or home screen.

Second, to save user details and then later use them to show on the home screen you can create a user `model class` and then save the object of that class in either the local storage using any method like the in-built SQLite database, or some libraries like Room or [PaperDB](https://github.com/pilgr/Paper). If you have a remote database, you can save the user details remotely and fetch them wherever required once the user is logged in.

Comment: Thanks Yash, may I know should I use firebase to create a database? Since I'm the beginner to develop android app, may I know how to deploy and implement SQLite database?

Answer (score 0):

> You can store login details in shared preference  after successful response

```
 private void saveLoginDetails() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);     
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(“PREF_UNAME_KEY”, “Pass user name”);
    editor.putBoolean(“PREF_ISLOGIN_KEY”, true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

> Function to read the preference values

```
private boolean checkIsLoggedIn() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  return settings.getBoolean(PREF_ISLOGIN_KEY, false);
}
```

> Check for isLogin on first screen (splash screen) while launching the app

```
if (checkIsLoggedIn()){
// start your home activity here     }
else{
// start signin or signup activity here
}
```